# evaluateJavaScript in QWebView doesn't call the javascript function

Tags: c++, qt, google-maps, google-maps-markers, qwebview

I have the following problem: I'm loading a map form HTML file in my code in QWebView (Google Maps). In this HTML file I defined a javascript function, which is supposed to add a labeled marker on map at specified coordinations. Here's the code:

JavaScript function:

```
function addLMarker(lat, lng, label) {
    var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        draggable: false,
        raiseOnDrag: false,
        map: map,
        labelContent: label,
        labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        labelClass: "labels",
        labelStyle: {opacity: 0.75}
    });
    markers.push(marker);
    return true;
}
```

C++ function:

```
QString SCRIPT_ADDMARKERWITHLABEL = tr("addLMarker(%1, %2, \"%3\")");
void addMarkerWithLabel(QPointF pos, QString label) {
    page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript(SCRIPT_ADDMARKERWITHLABEL.arg(pos.x()).arg(pos.y()).arg(label));
}
```

I'm sure the JS function is called correctly from my application, however it has no effect on my QWebView frame. When I call this function in a browser it executes correctly and places a marker on map at given position. Where is the problem? Am I missing something?

**EDIT:**
It suddenly started working. I realized that the function code was not executing correcly (despite working in browsers) so I turned on DeveloperExtras, so I could inspect what's going on with JS in my QWebView. I simply pasted this: `QWebSettings::globalSettings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::DeveloperExtrasEnabled, true);` to the constructor of my main window and the javascript code started working. After I removed this line it still keeps working. I wouldn't call it a solution, but well, it worked for me somehow.

Comment: If you pop an `alert("foo")` into your js function, do you see a messagebox? Also why the `tr()`? I'd be highly surprised if it was the cause of the issue, but seems odd to be marking a function name for translation! :P

Comment: Oh, yeah, this `tr()` there was from the times when I didn't exactly know what it does, of course it's unnecessary :) Yes, if I call just `alert("foo")` the alert shows up, same when I put it inside my function.

Comment: Cool well at least that shows that Qt is calling the function correctly. I'd guess then that the arguments are being passed from Qt to js incorrectly. Try triggering a message box from the js with all of the arguments you've passed to see what state they arrive in. I reckon you might need to change your `QString` to `SCRIPT_ADDMARKERWITHLABEL.arg(QString::number(pos.x()), QString::number(pos.y()), label)`

Comment: Tested it, the arguments are passed correctly. I found what's causing the problem - if I put `alert("foo")` when the function starts it's popping correcly, however it doesn't do anything when I put it AFTER creating new marker. That would mean the js code is faulty. Weird thing is it works in browsers like Chrome, FF and even Epiphany...

Comment: Mmm As a matter of curiosity do you wait the loadfinish signal in the webview before calling the first addLMarker? What happen if you enclose the marker new statement in a try catch block alerting a possible exception?

Comment: @Frexus I came across a similar problem 3 weeks ago but enabling the DeveloperExtras did not help me. Fooling Google Maps in believing that my QWebView is a "Chrome/1.0"-browser did. Maybe it can help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27730642/google-maps-draw-route-malfunction-in-windows