# Google Maps Draw Route malfunction in Windows

Tags: javascript, qt, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

*tldr: recently, my use of the Google Maps JavaScript API v3 does not show routes or markers anymore. It works fine on my Debian-box, but not on any Windows computer I tried (ranging XP to Windows 8). Has there been a recent change in the API? Is my code buggy? see http://pastebin.com/ubRGPtDZ*

---

Dear All,

in August 2014, I wrote a Qt program that at some stage shows Google Maps in a QWebView . Through JavaScript I was able to draw a route.

This program has been functioning fine, up to mid-December. On my Linux-box (Debian), it still works fine, but on every Windows computer I try, stops showing the route. Google Maps itself shows fine, but it stops showing any route, any marker, ...

Did anything change in Google Maps mid-December 2014? I checked the [changelog of Javascript Maps API v3](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/wiki/JavascriptMapsAPIv3Changelog) , but I do not see any new mention after September 2014.

Should I check somewhere else?

Or is there any change in QWebView-behaviour on Windows-boxes since mid December? Is that even possible?

I still hold possible that my JavaScript tweaking is inadequate, so I will debug that code as well, but definitely baffles me that everything worked fine for over 4 months on Windows-computers, and still does on my Debian-Box. I have put it online at http://pastebin.com/ubRGPtDZ .

My apologies for any bad English, non-native speaker here.

Thank you all for any suggestion.

Wim

Comment: see the [notify list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-maps-js-api-v3-notify), v3.18 became the release version on Nov 18, 2014.  You are using the [experimental version](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning) though, which may change at any time.  That said, the [code in your jsbin works for me (fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/no5uutn3/)

Comment: @geocodezip thank you very much for the response! Seriously, do I specify the experimental version? I thought I had to explicitly call for "v=3.exp". Maybe I trigger the experimental version by not mentioning a "v="? Good, I will make it "v=3".

Comment: @geocodezip one more question: I noticed my question has become downvoted. Was my question improper? I probably did not document myself enough and should have made an extra effort. Thank you for the effort to set me on the right track! Best wishes, Wim

Comment: it is ok question. I upvoted to help offset hater.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! This was a very frustrating challenge, but it feels great now that it is solved. It took me days of browsing through any documentation possible, of pure trial-and-error, testing and doubting every aspect of my code or even configuration, all failed... But one more time I browsed the qt-project and found this [post by lowsnr](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewreply/34236/) and [Yuvalal](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewreply/36423/).

In the words of lowsnr:

> as part of the test that the Google code performs    to determine
>   whether the browser is touch enabled,    it **checks the User Agent for**
>   **Chrome >= 5.0**, so by    changing the user agent to something like
>   ‘Chrome/1.0’    the touch interface suppressed.

Apparently it is also needed for displaying the directions (*). So I wrapped up a new class called `myWebPage` and derived it from `qWebPage`:

```
class myWebPage : public QWebPage
{
   virtual QString userAgentForUrl(const QUrl& url) const {
      return "Chrome/1.0";
   }
};
```

and before loading the [HTML](http://pastebin.com/ubRGPtDZ) in the qWebView, I use `setPage()`:

```
 ui->setupUi(this);
 ui->webView->setPage(new myWebPage());
 ui->webView->setHtml("...");
```

Now it works like a charm :-)

--

(*) For me, the prove that the problem was not my JavaScript, is that I tried to simply load the same HTML script as used in the [Google Maps code examples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple). In a QWebView, it works fine for my Linux-box, but refuses to show the directions on any Windows-compiled binary that I tried. Still, the code works fine if you load to a regular browser.

Conclusion: Google Maps does not necessary like QWebView.

Comment: Thanks to @geocodezip and nathaniel-johnson for the ideas, and if lowsnr or Yuvalal are here somewhere: thank you for the solution!